# Fully functional android data grid

Tags: android, datagrid, android-tablelayout

Since building dynamic table using Table Layout was not enough for me.
I wonder if I could get data grid view like this (from [MyData](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.portofarina.mydata&feature=search_result) application)

[image]

The features are:

1. vertical scrolling supported
2. horizontal scrolling supported
3. interactive table cells (for inserting data for example)
4. movable columns (long click on the column then move left or right)
5. sort columns

Are there any open source or commercial equivalent ?!

Comment: Did you found something?

Comment: We are working on a component that does this. http://blog.flexicious.com/post/Android-DataGrid.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [Basic Android spreadsheet](https://github.com/dennis-sheil/android-spreadsheet). Hope this may work.